# minimum mac os required for ios development

Tags: ios, macos

I want to start learning how to develop apps for the iPhone and the ipad but I don't want to shell out $1000+ for the latest mac.  I was wondering what is the lowest mac os required for development - snow leopard?  Are there any major reasons why you should have a mac running the latest os for development?

Answer (score 1):

iOS5 requires Xcode4 which requires Mac OS 10.7

Comment: Not true, Xcode 4 originally supported Snow Leopard. It's just no longer available as a download from Apple. Only the Lion version is.

Comment: You can still download the Snow Leopard version of Xcode if you are a paying developer program member (not sure if there is a free way).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to have the latest OS. You'll need the latest OS to install future iOS SDK's. Plus, with the Mac Dev program the OS is free anyway (Assuming you plan to develop for the Mac as well). Otherwise, Lion is only $29.

For the computer, if you really want to spend as possible, I'd recommend going with a Mac Mini which is $599. You'll need a monitor, but if you already have one at home, you can just buy the Thunderbolt to VGA adapter to hook it up to an existing VGA monitor.

Comment: I am thinking about getting an older macbook from 2006-2008 - I really like the style of those, the new macbooks dont tickle my fancy and I am not much of a desktop user (I prefer laptops).  So I was wonderin gif these older macbooks can even run OS Lion.  I saw one on ebay that was claiming to run OS lion but it was a 2006 model    - is that even possible?  If I were to get one of the older macbooks will i be able to install OS Lion so I can use it to develop stuff - is there a minimum system requirement?

Comment: The system requirements for Lion are 1 gb of RAM and a dual core processor I think. So, a 2006 MacBook may run Lion (not 100% sure), but I really wouldn't recommend that. Mountain Lion (the next OS being released this summer) drops support for many older MacBooks. So if you're going the used route, I would look for, at the very least, a 2008 MacBook Pro. For a regular MacBook, I wouldn't get anything earlier than 2009, or 2010. I still think the Mac Mini would be the best route for you because it's not too expensive and it's the latest model.